# Windows Azure response for Amazon Route 53

Tags: azure, dns, amazon-web-services, routes

In Amazon Route 53, I can host my domain and route to more than one server at AWS, it's right?!
Is it possible to do the same at Windows Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You would need to use a service like GoDaddy or DNSimple to register your domain name.  From there you could set up CName or A record rules to get to your Azure Windows hosted services.

Comment: Any expectations to launch something like?

Comment: @JoãoMello, traffic manager is expected to roll on some features along those lines

Answer (score 0):

there is no service now with exact features like Amazon Route 53 but Traffic Manager will be equipped with more features down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has released "Azure DNS Service" (currently in Preview)

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/dns